# transform categories to numbers in a csv file python

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv file like this

```
1,a,add
2,b,more
1,c,thinking
3,a,to
1,c,me
```

and I want to transform it the categories features into numerical format, like this :

```
1,0,0
2,1,1
1,2,2
3,0,3
1,2,4
```

But I have a problem : I cannot loop while reading and writing on a file in python, either it transforms only the second column, and it does nothing to the third or it transforms both the second and third, but not at the same time (similar to this :

```
1,0,add
2,1,more
1,2,thinking
3,0,to
1,2,me
1,a,0
2,b,1
1,c,2
3,a,3
1,c,4
```

So here is my code :

```
def construction_liste(reader, col):
    liste_mot_different=[]
    for line in reader:
        if line[col] not in liste_mot_different:
            liste_mot_different.append(line[col])
    #print liste_mot_different
    return liste_mot_different


def table_correspondance(liste):
    table_correspondance = []
    for i, item in enumerate(liste):
        table_correspondance.append((item,i))
    print table_correspondance
    return table_correspondance

def replace_word2int(line, table_correspondance):
    new_line = []
    for item in line:
        liste_table= [y[0] for y in table_correspondance]
        if item not in liste_table:
            new_line.append(item)
        else:
            i = [y[0] for y in table_correspondance].index(item)
            new_line.append(str(table_correspondance[i][1]))
    new_line = ",".join( new_line )
    new_line += "\n"
    print new_line
    return new_line

input_file = sys.argv[1]
output_file = sys.argv[2]

i1 = open( input_file, 'rb' )
i2 = open( input_file, 'rb' )

reader1=csv.reader( i1 )
reader2=csv.reader( i2 )

o = open( output_file, 'w' )

sequence = [2,5]

for col in seq:
    liste_mot_different=construction_liste(reader1,col)
    table_correspondance_word2int=table_correspondance(liste_mot_different)

    for line in reader2:
        nouvelle_ligne = replace_word2int(line, table_correspondance_word2int)
        o.write( nouvelle_ligne )



i1.close()
i2.close()
o.close()
```

In the 1st function, I look into each line for the same column, and construct a list of different string for the same column in all the lines
In the 2nd function, I onstruct a "map table", mapping an integer to a string from the list costructed previously
Int the 3rd function, in the file I replace all the strings by the corresponding integer, column by column

It does work for the 1st column in my sequence, but not fot the other ones, I think this is because once it has read all the lines it does not do it again ?

How could I do this ? thank you

I have also tried using `with [...] as` but it is not working neither

Comment: I'm finding it a bit hard to follow the code but "I think this is because once it has read all the lines it does not do it again ?" is correct. The issue though is that you should be using the `csv.writer()` instead, not `new_line = ",".join( new_line )` etc. Construct a nested list; `new_csv_data = [[row1col1, row1col2, row1col3], [row2col1, row2col2, row3col3],...]`. Then you can just `writerows`. However, with the current setup, I'm not clear how to aggregate this in a single list in `replace_word2int`.

Comment: You can also ditch `col` and just read each row without specifying the index. Then you only have to iterate the input file once and you can iterate your resulting list as many times as you want. You'll get a list structure just like the one I recommended in previous comment i.e. each row as a nested list, each element representing a column in that row

Comment: Ah, I understand what you've done now.

Comment: The one thing I don't understand to complete this; `i = [y[0] for y in table_correspondance].index(item)`. Are you saying that rather than `1, 2, 3, 4, 5` you could theoretically have `1, 2, 3, 2, 5` if there was a repeating word in your sample and never a `4`? In other words, if it's the first time you encounter that word, the value to replace that word with should be the index of the word and not the next unused number?